# HttpUrlConnection still waiting for timeout in the background after .Disconnect() is called

Tags: java, android

Im using HttpUrlConnection to do a http post call with the following code: (I call it from inside an AsyncTask)

```
    public List<String> realizarPostCall(String requestURL, HashMap<String, String> postDataParams) {

    URL url;
    List<String> response = new ArrayList<>();
    try {
        url = new URL(requestURL);

        conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setReadTimeout(45000);
        conn.setConnectTimeout(45000);
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        conn.setDoOutput(true);

        OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
                new OutputStreamWriter(os, "ISO-8859-1"));
        writer.write(getPostDataString(postDataParams));

        writer.flush();
        writer.close();
        os.close();
        int responseCode=conn.getResponseCode();

        if (responseCode == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            String line;
            BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
            while ((line=br.readLine()) != null) {
                response.add(line);
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        SincHttp.cancel(true);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if (response.size() == 0) {
        response.add(null);
    }
    return response;
}

private String getPostDataString(HashMap<String, String> params) throws UnsupportedEncodingException{
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    boolean first = true;
    for(Map.Entry<String, String> entry : params.entrySet()){
        if (first)
            first = false;
        else
            result.append("&");

        result.append(URLEncoder.encode(entry.getKey(), "ISO-8859-1"));
        result.append("=");
        result.append(URLEncoder.encode(entry.getValue(), "ISO-8859-1"));
    }

    return result.toString();
}
```

Now, when the user closes the activity, im trying to cancel the HttpUrlConnection conn by canceling my AsyncTask and calling conn.Disconnect(). It looks fine, it finishes the activity immediately but i see in the logcat that the connection is still waiting for the response from the server, after the timeout (45 seconds), my logcat show this:

```
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: failed to connect to /192.168.0.71 (port 8850) after 45000ms
```

How can i immediately cancel it? i was previously using the Apache Http Library wich is now deprecated and could cancel by calling .abort()

Comment: see this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6165752/in-java-how-close-the-connection-and-free-the-port-socket-using-httpurlconnecti

Comment: Does this thread help you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12383854/how-to-stop-httpurlconnection-connect-on-android  
Also, Any particular reason you're using HttpUrlConnection? We use OkHttp which has [cancel()](https://square.github.io/okhttp/2.x/okhttp/com/squareup/okhttp/OkHttpClient.html#cancel(java.lang.Object)) method that may fit your needs

Comment: no particular reason, im using it because it was the recommended native substitute to apache http. Also i tried OkHttp once, but i could not figure how to encode characters with accents to send the post (ISO-8859-1).